# Solve a system by putting new variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system: $$\begin{array}{|l}  
>  \dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{7}{25} \\  x^2+y^2=25  \end{array}$$

The first step is to determine the domain: $\begin{array}{|l} x \ne 0 \\ y \ne 0 \end{array}$

We can simplify the first equation of the system, and we get: $\begin{array}{|l} \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}=\dfrac{7}{25} \\ x^2+y^2=25 \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{|l} \dfrac{25}{xy}=\dfrac{7}{25} \\ x^2+y^2=25 \end{array}\Leftrightarrow \begin{array}{|l} 7xy=625 \\ x^2+y^2=25 \end{array}\Leftrightarrow \begin{array}{|l} xy=\dfrac{625}{7} \\ x^2+y^2=25 \end{array}\Leftrightarrow \begin{array}{|l} x=\dfrac{625}{7y} \\ x^2+y^2=25 \end{array}\Leftrightarrow \begin{array}{|l} x=\dfrac{625}{7y} \\ y^4-25y^2+\dfrac{390625}{49}=0 \end{array}$

The equation: $$y^4-25y^2+\dfrac{390625}{49}=0$$ has no solutions, so the whole system does not have a solution. In the text of the problem is said I should solve by "putting a new variable". I don't know how this method is called in English, and I would be grateful if you tell me. Let me give you a basic example of a system that can be solved using this method:
$$\begin{array}{|l} (x+2y)^2-(y-2x)^2=168 \\ (x+2y)^2+(y-2x)^2=12 \end{array}$$ 
Let $$\begin{array}{|l} (x+2y)^2=a \\ (y-2x)^2=b \end{array}...$$

Comment: I think they want you to rotate the axes to eliminate the $xy$ term in $x^2+y^2-\frac{7xy}{25}=0$.  See https://www.sparknotes.com/math/precalc/conicsections/section5/

Comment: Mm. We haven't studied sine and cosine.

Comment: if you let $b=\frac{x}{y}$ 

then 

$b+\frac{1}{b} = \frac{7}{25}$

 (the first equation) leads to a contradiction

Comment: I don't know what they want you to do then.  As far as I can see, your solution is correct.

Comment: Reducing it to a quadratic equation cannot really be improved.

Comment: @Lainad Yes, that immediately shows the first equation has no solution.  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Note a somewhat simpler way to handle this is to use $(x-y)^2 = x^2 - 2xy + y^2 = 25 - 2 \times \frac{625}{7} = -\frac{1075}{7}$, i.e., reduce it to a quadratic equation, with no real solutions, as suggested in this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476487/solve-a-system-by-putting-new-variables#comment7147437_3476487).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the first equation as
$$
\frac{x^2}{xy}+\frac{y^2}{xy}=\frac{7}{25}.
$$
The second equation then gives $\frac{625}{7}=xy$. Substituting gives
$$
49x^4 - 1225x^2 + 390625=0,
$$
which is a biquadratic equation with no real solution. This seems short enough.

Answer (score 2):

let $b=\frac{x}{y}$ (defined because $x\ne 0,y\ne 0$). Then by the first equation:

$b+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{7}{25}$

$\iff (b\ne0)$

$b^2-\frac{7}{25}b+1=0$

$\iff$

False (no real solutions)

so there are no solutions